# Gimp 2.10 crashes while looking for file data

Tags: windows-10, gimp

When I open gimp 2.10(the latest version), it loads fine until it gets to "Looking for file data Modules", and it stops responding and crashes. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Gimp from the website twice, both the normal and the compact version but it still won' t work. My specs are a windows 10 laptop with an intel i7 660U CPU, intel HD Graphics 520, and 16 gb of ram.

Comment: What did you install Gimp on? Did you satisfy any prerequisites for your machine? I have it on Kali 2021.2 (installlion) and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (software Updater) and it works fine in both systems.

Comment: @John I added my specs

Comment: I don't know. I only saw two things:  (1) possible conflict with Libre Office and (2) operating system issues - general fix was to try a Repair Install.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer, I do not know what caused the original error, but you need to install GIMP for ALL users instead of one to fix it.